# How to automatically improve Debugging in Symfony2

Tags: debugging, symfony, netbeans, xdebug

I tried debugging with Symfony2 before and dealing with the cache is a big pain in the head
I'm debugging with Netbeans and XDebug, is there a way to AUTOMATICALLY disable the cache and Debug in a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I added this code (based on [this official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/debugging.html)) in my app_dev.php in order to achieve exactly what I asked:

Changed:

`$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';`

with:

```
if( !isset($_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION']) )
    $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
else
    $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
```

and

`$kernel->loadClassCache();`

with

```
if( !isset($_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION']) )
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
```

Comment: May want to add relevant info for the console too. =)